# I want to create an EPG for tvOS along with pagination

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, iptv

I am trying to create EPG in tvOS, in which I have created collectionView flow layout successfully for a first set of data i.e. 24 channels and 4 hours programs.

I have created such thing in iOS in which user can scroll and once the user scrolls to a particular timeslot for which data is not available locally, it's fetched from the server and collection view is than populated.

For example, data for 22 channels and 4 hours from 4 pm to 8 pm is fetched, and then when user scrolls till 9 pm scale, data from 8 pm to 12 pm is fetched from server and collection view is populated.

In tvOS, a user is not allowed to scroll beyond the last cell, since there is not focusable view further.

I need help how to achieve behavior like iOS EPG in tvOS ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this. I'm working on same kind of requirement. If it is working for you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

tvOS will only allow you to move the focus among focusable cells. So you can not base the fetch logic in moving the focus to a position without cells.

On the other hand, to fetch the data for the next or previous page you could check if a cell close to the edge was selected, and proceed with the fetch of the new data.